# Request tag for Jedi Academy

Tags: support, tags

I didn't see a tag related to `Jedi`, or `Jedi Academy`, requesting it here.

It was a game, and I want to ask how to "bounce the weapon attack back"

[Wiki Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Jedi_Knight:_Jedi_Academy)

Comment: Do you have a question about the game? Are those even games? If you ask a question about a game, someone will edit in the tag

Comment: @murgatroid99 yes, question updated

Comment: As I said, *after* you ask the question someone can create the tag. Just tag it with anything when you ask it

Comment: For when you do ask a question, do you know a common shortening of the game title? The full title is too long to fit in a tag

Comment: @murgatroid99 This is funnier since the game is often called "Star Wars: Dark Forces 4: Jedi Knight 3: Jedi Outcast 2: Jedi Academy"